# wait for children and grand-children

Tags: c, unix, signals

How can you wait until all children and grand-children have exited, without blocking in a signal handler? This is my attempt so far.

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int run = 1;

void handler(int sig, siginfo_t *info, void *uap)
{
    int exit_code;

    printf("sigchld pid %d\n", info->si_pid);
    pid_t pid = waitpid(-1, &exit_code, 0);
    if (pid == -1) {
        perror("waitpid()\n");
    } else {
        printf("waitpid returned %d\n", pid);
    }
    // set run = 0 when all children exit

    printf("end of sigchild handler\n");
}

void main() {

    struct sigaction chld;
    chld.sa_sigaction = handler;
    chld.sa_flags = SA_NOCLDSTOP | SA_SIGINFO;
    sigaction(SIGCHLD, &chld, NULL);

    //procmask sigchld?
    if (!fork ()) {
        if (!fork ()) {
            sleep(2);
            printf ("grand-son exit: %d\n", getpid());
            exit (0);
        }
        sleep(1);
        printf ("son exit: %d\n", getpid());
        exit (0);
    }

    while(run)
        sleep(1);

    printf("ciao\n");
}
```

Comment: You can't wait for grandchildren; if a child exits without having waited for its own children, then those children will typically be reassigned to a "root" or "init" process. (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orphan_process.)

Comment: 1) main returns int. 2) don't use printf() in a signal handler. 3) forking twice is a way for the grandchild to detach from the grandparent process (but some additional syscalls may be necessary to detach from the terminal(group))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While it is true that SIGCHLD and `waitpid`, etc., only work for immediate children, on UNIX systems you can often "cheat" a little bit with inherited resources passed from parent to child to grandchild, and closed upon process termination.

For example, the original process might open a [`pipe`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pipe.html), and perhaps set the *read* end of it [close-on-exec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fcntl.html), so that children and grandchildren inherit the write end.  When the original process is ready to wait for all descendants to terminate, it closes its write end of the pipe and blockingly `read`s or `select`s for readability on the remaining descriptor.  When the last descendant has terminated, the read end of the pipe will deliver an EOF.

This tactic is not guaranteed — a child or grandchild might cautiously close inherited file descriptors — but it often works well enough.