# How to wait for grandchild process (`bash` retval becomes -1 in Perl due to SIG CHLD)

Tags: bash, perl, wait, background-process, child-process

I have a Perl script (snippet below) that runs in cron to perform system checks. I fork a child as a timeout and reap it with SIG{CHLD}. Perl does several system calls of Bash scripts and checks their exit status. One bash script fails about 5% of the time with no error. The Bash scripts exists with 0 and Perl sees $? as -1 and $! as "No child processes".

This bash script tests compiler licenses, and Intel icc is left around after the Bash script completes (ps output below). I think the icc zombie completes, forcing Perl into SIG{CHLD} handler, which blows away the $? status before I'm able to read it.

```
Compile status -1; No child processes
```

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use POSIX ':sys_wait_h';

my $GLOBAL_TIMEOUT = 1200;

### Timer to notify if this program hangs
my $timer_pid;
$SIG{CHLD} = sub {
    local ($!, $?);
    while((my $pid = waitpid(-1, WNOHANG)) > 0)
    {
        if($pid == $timer_pid)
        {
            die "Timeout\n";
        }
    }
};

die "Unable to fork\n" unless(defined($timer_pid = fork));
if($timer_pid == 0)  # child
{
    sleep($GLOBAL_TIMEOUT);
    exit;
}
### End Timer

### Compile test
my @compile = `./compile_test.sh 2>&1`;
my $status = $?;
print "Compile status $status; $!\n";
if($status != 0)
{
    print "@compile\n";
}

END  # Timer cleanup
{
    if($timer_pid != 0)
    {
        $SIG{CHLD} = 'IGNORE';
        kill(15, $timer_pid);
    }
}

exit(0);
```

```
#!/bin/sh

cc compile_test.c
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Cray compiler failure"
    exit 1
fi

module swap PrgEnv-cray PrgEnv-intel
cc compile_test.c
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Intel compiler failure"
    exit 1
fi

wait
ps
exit 0
```

The wait doesn't really wait because cc calls icc which creates a zombie grandchild process that wait (or wait PID) doesn't block for. (wait `pidof icc`, 31589 in this case, gives "not a child of this shell")

```
user 31589     1  0 12:47 pts/15   00:00:00 icc
```

I just don't know how to fix this in Bash or Perl.

Thanks, Chris

Comment: It looks like you are going to a lot of trouble to avoid using `alarm`.  Is there a reason not to use `alarm` here?

Comment: Your SIGCHLD handler is also reaping the shell spawned by the backticks, so the `waitpid` call done by the backticks fails (since the child has already been reaped).

Comment: I have several `bash` calls in the real Perl script. Only this one fails periodically. Just noticed today the icc left behind, that "wait" can't catch.

Comment: "_this one fails_" -- I didn't get what fails? The fact that `icc` stays around (which is awkward), or is there an actual error?  Note that "_Compile status -1; No child processes_" isn't an error since you have a `CHLD` handler _and_ check `$?` after backticks, which may have gotten reaped by handler (so the only error is doing both).  Also, from what you show it appears that `cc` starts `icc` and doesn't wait for it ...? (Are you sure? That sounds really strange to me.)

Comment: Note, you can't really check `wait 31589` (or such) since you don't know what PID of a child is in the current run (it is most likely different from what it was in previous runs).

Comment: So the local($?,$!) in SIG{ALRM} doesn't keep the values within the reaper. I guess there is no way to keep $? from \`bash\` from being clobbered?

Comment: "_doesn't keep the values within the reaper_" -- I don't understand: the handler is a sub that runs and exits and values in there are lost.  Whatever you want out of a signal handler need be assigned to global variables. (You can have a hash keyed by pids, for example, and assign to it once you check that it reaped a process you want.)  I am not sure what `local $?` is for -- if it's meant to protect stuff outside of handler that won't work: The handler reaps the signal about the exited child so backticks (waitpid that is run by the system for it) just has nothing, thus the -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought the quickest solution would be to add sleep of a second or two at the bottom of the bash script to wait for the zombie icc to complete. But that didn't work.

If I didn't already have a SIG ALRM (in the real program) I agree the best choice would be to wrap the whole thing in a eval. Even thought that would be pretty ugly for a 500 line program.

Without the local($?), **every** `system` call gets $? = -1. The $? I need in this case is after waitpid, then unfortunately set to -1 after the sig handler exits. So I find this works. **New lines shown with ###**

```
my $timer_pid;
my $chld_status;    ###
$SIG{CHLD} = sub {
    local($!, $?);
    while((my $pid = waitpid(-1, WNOHANG)) > 0)
    {
        $chld_status = $?;    ###
        if($pid == $timer_pid)
        {
            die "Timeout\n";
        }
    }
};

...
my @compile = `./compile_test.sh 2>&1`;
my $status = ($? == -1) ? $chld_status : $?;    ###
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this a use case for [`alarm`](http://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#alarm)? Toss out your SIGCHLD handler and say

```
local $? = -1;
eval {
    local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "Timeout\n" };
    alarm($GLOBAL_TIMEOUT);
    @compile = `./compile_test.sh 2>&1`;
    alarm(0);
};

my $status = $?;
```

instead.

Comment: There are tons of other items the Perl script does. I just cut out the part that fails. There already is a SIG ALRM in there for something else, but maybe you can have one nested in another? The SIG CHLD was an overall timeout.

Comment: You can't have nested alarms, but a `local $SIG{ALRM} = ...` can overwrite the SIGALRM handler until the end of the scope in which it was defined.

Comment: Consider [Time::Out](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Out) to do nested alarms sensibly.

Comment: The value of `$status` is mostly garbage. `-1` normally means to use `$!`, but it you can't tell if it means that here, and `$!` was clobbered by `alarm(0)` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar issue, here is our solution: Leak a write-side file descriptor into the grandchild and read() from it which will block until it exits.

See also: [wait for children and grand-children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8391938/wait-for-children-and-grand-children/)

```
use Fcntl;

# OCF scripts invoked by Pacemaker will be killed by Pacemaker with
# a SIGKILL if the script exceeds the configured resource timeout. In
# addition to killing the script, Pacemaker also kills all of the children
# invoked by that script. Because it is a kill, the scripts cannot trap
# the signal and clean up; because all of the children are killed as well,
# we cannot simply fork and have the parent wait on the child. In order
# to work around that, we need the child not to have a parent proccess
# of the OCF script---and the only way to do that is to grandchild the
# process. However, we still want the parent to wait for the grandchild
# process to exit so that the OCF script exits when the grandchild is
# done and not before. This is done by leaking the write file descriptor
# from pipe() into the grandchild and then the parent reads the read file
# descriptor, thus blocking until it gets IO or the grandchild exits. Since
# the file descriptor is never written to by the grandchild, the parent
# blocks until the child exits.
sub grandchild_wait_exit
{
    # We use "our" instead of "my" for the write side of the pipe. If
    # we did not, then when the sub exits and $w goes out of scope,
    # the file descriptor will close and the parent will exit.
    pipe(my $r, our $w);

    # Enable leaking the file descriptor into the children
    my $flags = fcntl($w, F_GETFD, 0) or warn $!;
    fcntl($w, F_SETFD, $flags & (~FD_CLOEXEC)) or die "Can't set flags: $!\n";

    # Fork the child
    my $child = fork();
    if ($child) {
        # We are the parent, waitpid for the child and
        # then read to wait for the grandchild.
        close($w);
        waitpid($child, 0);
        <$r>;
        exit;
    }

    # Otherwise we are the child, so close the read side of the pipe.
    close($r);

    # Fork a grandchild, exit the child.
    if (fork()) {
        exit;
    }

    # Turn off leaking of the file descriptor in the grandchild so
    # that no other process can write to the open file descriptor
    # that would prematurely exit the parent.
    $flags = fcntl($w, F_GETFD, 0) or warn $!;
    fcntl($w, F_SETFD, $flags | FD_CLOEXEC) or die "Can't set flags: $!\n";
}

grandchild_wait_exit();

sleep 1;
print getppid() . "\n";
print "$$: gc\n";
sleep 30;
exit;
```

Comment: Note that getppid() returns "1" because the grandchild's parent (the parent's 1st child) has exited so the grandchild is re-parented to the "init" process.

Comment: Is the "init" process this one then?

init
--> child
       --> grandchild

Comment: parent -> child -> grandchild, but when child exits it becomes parent -> [none], init -> grandchild